# Valence PUT grade getting 404

Tags: desire2learn

Grade submission though valence is giving me issues.

Trying to model the request per https://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html#put--d2l-api-le-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-%28D2LID-orgUnitId%29-grades-%28D2LID-gradeObjectId%29-values-%28D2LID-userId%29

```
Oct 9, 2012 8:20:02 AM com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 3 * Client out-bound request
3 > PUT http{s}://elearning.test.masked.edu:443/d2l/api/le/1.0/47908/grades/217237/values/37185   (Yes the x_a, x_b, and x_t parameters are set and correct)

{"GradeObjectType":4,"Text":"1052012"}
```

The response is always a 404.

```
Oct 9, 2012 8:20:02 AM com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 3 * Client in-bound response
3 < 404
```

To rule out permission issues and ensure the values were correct, I logged in through D2L's user interface and set a grade using the user who is making the valence call. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the date was past the course end date. D2L allows for grades to be viewed and submitted through the web page after the course end date, but not currently through the Valence API. This is a known issue with releases 9.4.1 through 10.1.0 and D2L reports that the issue is in their internal defect tracking system for fixing. ***Comment Edited per D2L suggestion.  Thanks for the help.***

Comment: I have confirmed this problem now. Can you please report this as an issue in our issue tracker (https://d2l.fogbugz.com/default.asp?pg=pgPublicEdit),  so that your contact info can be associated with the issue in order for you to follow its progress?

Comment: Bug created.  Thank you for having a public bug tracker.  Off topic, but I also created bug #2052.  It's something that would help us.